# Slow start after suspend

Tags: laptop

So basically the trouble its that every time that i wake the laptop, after i put my password it stays in this black screen for 4-7 seconds, i was thinking that this was because i was using a hdd, but now i'm with a ssd and this stayed, it happens independently of the use of the computer, even if the computer its without any program open, what can i do?
[image]